# C++ code creating Lua 5.3.6 tables always returns attempt to call a table value

Tags: c++, lua

Nothing I do seems to work and I've tried everything known to mankind at this point.

Here is C code:

```
int l_getHeader(lua_State* L)
{
    lua_createtable(L, 0, 5);
    lua_pushnumber(L, asset);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "asset");
    lua_pushnumber(L, partner);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "partner");
    lua_pushnumber(L, collector);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "collector");
    lua_pushnumber(L, tm);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "time");
    lua_pushnumber(L, count);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "count");
    lua_pushnil(L);
    lua_setglobal(L, "header");

    return 1
```

and here is the lua call

```
function load_header()
    local header = {}
    -- still not sure if should assign return
    get_header()
    -- header = get_header()
    print("asset " .. header["asset"])
    print("partner " .. header["partner"])
    print("collector " .. header["collector"])
    print("time " .. header["time"])
    print("count " .. header["count"])
end
```

I always get the same error. I've tried pushing all items onto the stack, rawset, etc. NADA!! This is the simplest example I could come up with that also doesn't work and seemingly should.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] but my guess would be that `get_header` is not your c function `l_getHeader`

Comment: `local header = get_header()` looks more correct

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `l_getHeader` pushes it's value into a global variable rather than leaving it on the stack to be returned

Comment: Why do you `lua_pushnil`?

Comment: get_header is the name of getHeader when exposed to Lua